# Cannot declare static constexpr char []

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, static, constexpr

I've read all the answers related with this issue but honestly I'm not sure if I've fully understand the solution. I'm using C++11.

Lets say I really would like to declare something like `static constexpr char value[] = "foo"`.

If I use NetBeans/TDM_MINGW I get an error which I suppose is a link error reporting **undefined reference to "variable_name"**.

Trying the same code in MS VS 2015 I get **"expression did not evaluate to a constant"**.

A simple `static constexpr char *` solves the problem but I lost the ability of using expressions like `sizeof`.

Simple and straightforward questions (if possible straightforward anwsers) :

1. Is there a way to declare a **`static constexpr char []`** inside `struct`/`class`?
2. If 1) is false is there a cleanest solution to overcome this? **`static constexpr char *`**????
3. Or the old **`static const char []`** is still the best approach for this case?
4. I've tested a solution that works but far from being "clean" `static constexpr array<char,50> getConstExpr(){
   return array<char,50> {"Hell"}
   }`. It works fine but I have to declare the size of the char `std::array` :(

Comment: hmm, tested with mingw64 (4.9.2) and with gcc of same version and that line worked. Problem with limited c++11 support? Can you give references to what you had read? static constexpr memeber variables  are supported only since C++14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Is there a way to declare a `static constexpr char []` inside `struct`/`class`?

Yes; it's simple.

The following is a full working example

```
struct bar
 { static constexpr char value[] = "foo"; };

constexpr char bar::value[];

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << bar::value << std::endl; // print foo
 }
```

I suppose You forgot the `bar::value[]` row.

> 2) If 1) is false is there a cleanest solution to overcome this `static constexpr char *` ????

Not applicable.

> 3) Or the old `static const char []` is still the best approach for this case?

Depend from the problem you have to solve; but usually I suggest to avoid C-style arrays and use the new C++11 `std::array`

> 4) I've tested a solution that works but far from being "clean" [...] It works fine but I have to declare the size of the char `std::array` :(

I propose you a solution (unfortunately work starting from C++14, but isn't too difficult make a C++11 version) to detect the correct size from `"Hell"` passed as parameter.

Observe the use of `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` to pass the single chars from the `char[]` variable to the `std::array`.

```
template <std::size_t Dim, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr std::array<char, Dim> gceH (char const (&str)[Dim],
                                      std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return { { str[Is]... } }; }

template <std::size_t Dim>
constexpr std::array<char, Dim> getConstExpr (char const (&str)[Dim])
 { return gceH(str, std::make_index_sequence<Dim>{}); }

int main ()
 {
   constexpr auto f = getConstExpr("Hell");

   static_assert( 5U == f.size(), "!" );
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

As suggested by Swift (thanks!) using a template type, instead `char`, transform `getConstExpr()` in a more flexible function.

So `getConstExpr()` and the helper function (`gceH()`) can be written as follows

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Dim, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr std::array<T, Dim> gceH (T const (&str)[Dim],
                                   std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return { { str[Is]... } }; }

template <typename T, std::size_t Dim>
constexpr std::array<T, Dim> getConstExpr (T const (&str)[Dim])
 { return gceH(str, std::make_index_sequence<Dim>{}); }
```

Comment: would be good to make char - type of array element - a parameter of template too, wouldn't taht allow reuse of template?

Comment: Tank you for your objective answer @max66. I did forget to declare it outside class scope. Nice to have you around.

Comment: @Swift - why not? Answer modified following your suggestion.

Comment: @JacintoResende - answer improved following the suggestion from Swift

Comment: In C++17, it is no more necessary to declare it outside the class scope. MS VS Community 2017 does support it and is free for personal use. On Linux, clang version 5.0 does support it too.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++17 you don't need to do anything special, because `static constexpr` member variables are implicitly `inline`.

Following will work:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    static constexpr char value[] = "Meow!\n";
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << S::value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid C-style arrays, there is also a C++17 solution using the std::string_view... which is much more simple. ;)

Here is a [perm-link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nSDX0iXqP1sIYLhn) of the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main ()
{
    constexpr std::string_view foo ( "Hell" );
    static_assert ( 4U == foo.size (), "!" );

    std::cout << "Done";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```